# Let $N\geq2$ be s.t. $X_1\geq X_2\geq...\geq X_{N-1}\lt X_N$, shoe that $E[N] = e$

Tags: probability

> Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed continuous random variables. Let $N\geq2$ be s.t. $X_1\geq X_2\geq...\geq X_{N-1}\lt X_N$, show that $E[N] = e$.

My thoughts:

Since the statement is true for any continuous random variables, I think it is related to central limit theorem. Also, I tried to let $Y_n = X_n - X_{n-1}$ to reformulate the problem to "$Y_N$ is the first positive $Y_i$". But I don't know how to continue. Could you please give me some hints? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

By continuity, the probability of any equalities among the $X_k$ is 0, so we can disregard those. Now, for $k$ variables, the probability that you observe them without reaching $N$, is the probability that you observe them in exactly descending order, which is $\mathbb P(N > k) = 1/k!$. Thus
$$
\mathbb E[N] = \sum_{k \in \mathbb N_+} \mathbb P(N \geq k) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb N} \mathbb P(N > k) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb N} \frac1{k!} = e.
$$

Comment: May I ask why is $P\{N>k\}=1/k!$ ?

Comment: @Longitude, that is the first part of my answer. What about it do you not understand?

Comment: For those wondering: we have $\mathbb P(N>k)=\mathbb P(X_1\geq\dots \geq X_k)=1/k!$, since for any permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\dots,k\}$, we have $\mathbb P(X_1\geq\dots X_k)=\mathbb P(X_{\sigma(1)}\geq\dots X_{\sigma(k)})$, and $\vert S_k\vert=k!$.